# Laptop as wireless IIS Server

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, iphone, iis

Let me explain the situation.

I have a laptop & an iPhone. 
I have installed .NET on my laptop. 
Using .NET I have developed few web-services.
I want to use that web-services to my iPhone.
In .NET, we can run a local IIS Server.

My question is '***How is it possible to Access that LOCAL IIS server using iPhone?
I have no internet connection over my phone & my laptop. Is it possible without additional hardwares & free applications ?***'

Comment: what OS does the laptop run? i'm guessing windows, but which particular version?

Comment: @J.Geek - It has Windows 7 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty straightforward.

You need your wireless card in your laptop to run as a wireless access point. This may depend on the exact hardware you have, but Windows 7 Ultimate should let you do it.

If you run the IIS server and have it configured to listen on the wireless NIC, you will then just be able to connect directly to it with your iPhone by entering IP address and port as you would expect.

update to include comment:

Try something like **[connectify](http://connectify.me)** - a free app to make your laptop into an access point, then just connect your iPhone to that wireless network and point a browser at that URL

Comment: Does my laptop require any kind of internet connection for being wireless access point ?

Comment: No - unless you are needing to connect to the internet for some other reason.

Comment: I have Dell Inspiron N4010 & It has a wireless Card. What should be the steps to enable such thing ? I mean - Assume - I am running http://localhost:9552/mySite/myWebService.aspx. How to explore this page on iPhone ?

Comment: updated answer with 'connectify'

Answer (score -2):

just go to your modem settings at 192.168.1.1 and set a port forwarding for the local port to your laptop ip address

Comment: The OP doesn't even have a router or internet connection. Port forwarding applies to WAN ports, which in turn require an internet connection, so your answer doesn't really answer the question, sorry.